# C# get api response for debugging

Tags: c#, rest

I am trying to get api response based on apiurl as parameter using c# code as below. Things are working fine but I am unable to debug and see the final json response. Is there any other option to get the api response to a variable to debug and check final complete response. Will this approach of getting api json has any issues?

```
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<string> GET(string url)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", BearerToken);
            try
                {
                    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                        return reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
                    using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                        String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                    throw;
                }
}
```

Comment: `Httpclient` is the modern, much simpler way to do this.

Comment: I tried in past to get complete exception, but i was unable to get all details at once. So I tried bit different approach. Check this link might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721796/how-to-throw-exception-from-webapi

Comment: As for me, HttpClient doesn't have an interface, hence not mockable and not flexible for API testing. Please, have a look at Refit, there is a complete guide on how to utilize the library here -> https://github.com/reactiveui/refit